# C# simple device application is throwing Class not registered exception

Tags: c#, device, motorola

I wrote a simple program to read barcode using Motorola mc5040 SDK

As soon as below code line gets executed

```
CCoreScanner cCoreScanner = new CCoreScanner();
```

Following exception gets thrown

> exp.Message = "COM object with CLSID '{9F8D4F16-xxx-xxxx-98B3-xxxx}' cannot be created due to the following error: Class not registered ."

Any pointers how to resolve this ? I am running simple windows form with one button and a text box on actual Device running Windows CE.

Comment: Are you sure you added the Library of the Motorola to your project / and the right version (32/64bit) this could be a problem. Furthermore on windows it can be different to compile in the different .NET Frameworks (maybe try using 4.5 / 4.5 Client profile)

Comment: regasm.exe whateverCom.dll /codebase ... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tzat5yw6%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: you need to register it...